# Can we Get the Session Values in Views in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can we Get those  Values which is  in Session directly  in asp.net MVC Views?

I have tried it in Controller it Works,I can easily get & set the Value,

But how to Get value directly from Session in Views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but you shouldn't as this is considered as bad practice. Views are not supposed to pull data. They should use data passed from the controller. So in your controller read the session and then pass the value to the view for rendering. This rule can be easily broken by using the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.session(v=VS.100).aspx) property of the View page:

```
<%= this.Session["someKey"] %>
```

Comment: how to do it with MVC 4?